# Configure expand selection in Visual Studio Code to select the whole identifier

Tags: visual-studio-code

The first invocation of the Expand Selection (`Alt-Shift-RightArrow` by default) in VSCode selects camel-case sub-word under the cursor. For example, when the cursor is placed inside a camel-case identifier (such `GetComponentsInChildren`), it selects "Components" or "Children".

I have tested that in C# source code. I have "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)" extension installed.

Is it possible to configure Expand Selection to include the whole identifier GetComponentsInChildren? I really prefer it to be consistent with the behavior of other navigation and selection options (`Ctrl-RightArrow` - jump to the right, `Ctrl-D` - add selection to next find match)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today (actually the [June 2023 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80), or `1.80`), there's a setting that controls this exact behaviour, namely `"editor.smartSelect.selectSubwords"`; if you set it to `false`, the editor will select the whole word the first time you expand the selection without paying attention to subwords in camel case (or any other case for that matter).

Still, I have to say I appreciate the ingenuity of the other answers - there's a lot that can be done with macros and `when` clause contexts.

Answer (score 4):

Originally I thought you could simply make a macro to run 2 `smartSelect.expand` commands in a row (as in the commented code below).  That does work  - except for single words like `someword` with no camelCase - and then the first `grow` selects the entire word under the cursor and the second `grow` selects the line or enclosing block, not what you want.

```
"multiCommand.commands": [    // in settings.json

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.selectWord",
    "sequence": [

      // "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
      // "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",

      "cursorWordStartLeft",
      "cursorWordRightSelect",
    ]
  }
]
```

So I looked for another way to do it and I think I found it with the macro above (which uses the multi-command extension).  And this in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+right",    // disable so you can use the same keybinding
  "command": "-editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},

{
  "key": "shift+alt+right",    // trigger the macro with the same keybinding if you wish
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.selectWord" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

The downside to this approach is that you lose the `smartSelect.expand` beyond the current word - it will not expand to the containing block for example.  You decide if that is important to you.  If you use a different keybinding then you don't have to disable the `smartSelect grow` command and you can have both options.

[image: demo of selecting whole word]

---

As of v1.44 the behaviour of `Add Selection to Next Find Match` has changed in how it calculates the word definition.  Perhaps it is better for you.

> The command `Add Selection to Next Find Match`
>   (kb(`editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch`)) now respects the
>   setting `editor.wordSeparators`. Previously, it used to pick up the word
>   definition as defined by the current file's language.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed investigation! Marking it as an answer, even though it essentially means this option cannot be configured at the moment (workaround is too limiting). :) Just FYI, the best approximation I am using for now is Ctrl/Cmd+D. It selects full word under the cursor on first invocation (and next entry of the same word on the next invocation).

Comment: > "The downside to this approach is that you lose the smartSelect.expand beyond the current word"

To fix this, you can modify your "when" clause to this:
`"when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"`

Comment: where is this `multiCommand.selectWord` coming from?

Comment: @slier It is shown in the answer defined in the `settings.json`.

Answer (score 1):

There was a comment about adding more to the when clause. That didn't exactly work for me, but I was able to add to it to get the result I was expecting.

my `keybindings.json`:

```
...
{
    "key": "cmd+up",    // disable so you can use the same keybinding
    "command": "-editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+up", // when the editor has a word, grow the selection (this ignore camel case)
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.grow" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+up", // when the editor doesn't have a word selected, select entire word, ignoring camelcase (editor.action.smartSelect.grow won't ignore camel case on first word select)
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.selectWord" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
}
...
```

my `settings.json` (unchanged from original answer):

```
...
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.selectWord",
      "sequence": [
        "cursorWordStartLeft",
        "cursorWordRightSelect",
      ]
    }
  ]
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that this requires installing the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension to work.