# Change `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` to not treat camelCase words as boundaries?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have a variable called `helloWorld`, and I put my cursor somewhere in `World`, and run  `editor.action.smartSelect.grow`, it'll just select "World". Is there a setting to make it select the entire variable, `helloWorld`? I want it to behave more like IntelliJ.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? This triggers me so much 

Comment: @Lulupointu Nope. Still never does what I want it to do 

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: [Configure expand selection in Visual Studio Code to select the whole identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048606/configure-expand-selection-in-visual-studio-code-to-select-the-whole-identifier) There are some answers there already!

Answer (score 2):

Just disable the following setting: "Editor > Smart Select: Select Subwords".

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by one of the following commands.

> editor.action.smartSelect.expand
> editor.action.smartSelect.grow (obsolete)

[edit: Obsolete, vscode has camelCase navigation/smartSelection since v1.25]

An important prerequisite is to have the feature of *camel case navigation* enabled. For some inexplicable reason, VS Code doesn't come with it by default and requires one to install an extension for it.

My suggestion for camelizaton is [*Camel Case Navigation from Maptz*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.camelcasenavigation), which can be installed from the GUI or by the command below. Try out your camel humping by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> to verify the functionality.

> code --install-extension maptz.camelcasenavigation

I've mapped the expansion and shrinkage in my *settings.json* the following way.

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+right", 
  "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.expand", 
  "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+left", 
  "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.shrink", 
  "when": "editorTextFocus" }, ...
```

I've been told on occasion that some people experienced that functionality to be distorted, though. Unable to confirm that, we speculated that it was due to an unfortunate combination of expansions and plugins, possibly colliding somehow. May that be the case in your editor?

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of keybindings, it's the behavior of `editor.action.smartSelect.expand` that's wonky. If I put my cursor after the `Sel` in `editor.action.smartSelect.expand` and activate it, it selects "Select.expand" whereas I'd expect it to select "smartSelect".

Comment: @mpen Based on that information, I agree with the wonkyness in it. Intuitively, I would suspect that you're actually not performing *expand*, although you believe that you do. However, it appears that you've already thought of that, so it's a dead-end. I'm assuming that you've installed the latest update and the issue remains still. Do you get the same misbehavior if you use *smartSelect.grow* as with *smartSelect.expand*? It would also be interesting to investigate if the issue remains when all extensions are removed (new installation on a new user account). Have you tried that too?

Comment: `grow` and `expand` seem to behave the same. No, I haven't tried disabling all my extensions. Unless there's an easy to temporarily disable them, like a 'safe mode', then I'd rather not. I did try on 2 different installs though. And I upgraded to 1.55.1 just now; still works the same way.

Comment: That's definitely weird shit. The only thing I can imagine is the collision with other extensions but if you had it installed on another system then it was vanilla at start. Perhaps you didn't think to test it prior to pushing in your extension junk first, though. I believe you can disable an extension (on each extension's screen, there's a button *disable* next to *uninstall*. Given that you've tried the stuff on updated VSCode on two separate systems, I say it's one of two things. Your extensions or magic. Take your pick.   :)

Comment: Both installs had extensions. But here.. I just installed VS Code fresh into Windows Sandbox. Completely stock. No extensions. No customization. Latest ver straight from the website: https://mpen.xyz/share/2021/04/chrome_2021-04-09_19-12-48.png Same behavior. Are you sure this isn't how it's *supposed* to behave? Does it do something different for you?

Comment: I'm flabbergasted. To answer your question - yes, I'm totally sure that it's **my** way that is the supposed behavior. That sureness is based on the years of experience with Code and on quadruple check with a few other people. There's definitely something spooky with your system. In fact, I love those weirdy gotchas, so if you are up for it, I can set up a video meeting so you can see my screen and compare what **you** do on your computer with what happens on **mine**. I'm sure there's a small difference that we fail to realize now and in the end we'll go *what the duck*.

Comment: And just to be clear - I entirely believe you. That's why I'm so amazed and wiling to engage that little duck for an issue. The only thing (and it's a silly shot, definitely) is to exclude that your *alt* is weird. Can you test *ctrl+w* or something (just make sure that you remove the original key binding for it (I think it closes a tab, originally). The behavior displayed corresponds to *ctrl+shift+end* (but not quite). Also, I'd like to know what happens if you expand a few times? And what if you then shrink? Is it working "properly'ish" (although only on one side of the cursor origin)?

Comment: Here's a video I recorded: https://mpen.xyz/share/2021/04/2021-04-11_14-43-53.mp4 I used Ctrl+Shift+P to choose "expand" instead of using a hotkey just to prove it wasn't some weird hotkey conflict. Also, I did try with both the default (shift+alt+right) and my preference of ctrl+w. I think it depends on the language, whether or not it wants to expand over a "." or not. And here's a comparison with PhpStorm: https://mpen.xyz/share/2021/04/2021-04-11_14-49-17.mp4 which is what I'm used to and prefer.

Comment: @mpen I just realized something that might help us here. Camel-casing isn't a part of VS Code bu default (which itself is a weird thing, in my opinion). So to get the concept of camel-casing (i.e. capitals being regarded as delimiters for CTRL+arrow etc.), one **is required** to install an extension. Now, without any extension, the behavior is as expected (no camelization as a feature). With an extension for camel humping (if it's not working), it's likely that the extension is ducked up.

Comment: @mpen So, the question is *have you had an extension for camel humping installed?* and if not, let's try to get one (I'm avoiding a recommendation intentionally unless asked to). And if you wonder why on Earth VSC doesn't provide the camel-case concept by default, get in line. There are many of us wondering. Whoever took that design decision at MS made a huge boo-boo. Try if *CTRL+right* gives you expected humping and **then** if the smart select performs as expected.

Comment: No, I don't have any "camel humping" extensions. Which do you recommend? I can try with that and see if it behaves more like I'd expect.

Comment: @mpen Ah, well, there you go - that may be the root cause of your problem. And there's no shade of blame on you for missing it. Whoever decided not to add camelization by default in an editor explicitly intended for programmers is IM(not-very)HO a retarded banana. I use [*Came Case Navigation* from Maptz](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.camelcasenavigation) (*code --install-extension maptz.camelcasenavigation*). Let me know if that kills your issue and if it does, I'll be so happy (and you'll +1 me for the effort, of course, hehe).

Comment: @mpen I edited the answer to include the hint on camelization functionality. I suggest that we remove the comments once the solution is confirmed. They don't bring anything useful to the content of my answer now. Also, I'm curious how you made the movie and how you distributed it. That skill may come in handy sometime.

Comment: I installed the extension. I don't think it affects the smartSelect.expand functionality. It does offer some new hotkeys though, like `ExtendCamelRightCommand ` but that's not what I was looking for either. It's okay. It's not that big of a deal :-) And you deserve an upvote for your effort :-D

Comment: I used ShareX to record those videos. I have it set to upload to Backblaze B2. And then I put Cloudflare in front of that for the custom domain + it helps keep my costs down because they have a free egress deal and Cloudflare does some caching.

Comment: @mpen I'm not entirely sure if I understand. Are you saying that you **sill** don't get the cursor to jump to the next capital (with ctrl+arrow) or select text to next capital (with ctrl+shift+arrow)? I understand that the original issue is to smart select by widening the section in both directions. But that feature is based in the capacity to find delimiters, so I'm trying to figure out if it's the cameling that fails in your system or something else. (I hate giving up on a stupid computer glitch. We need to fight the machines, you know.)

Comment: I can get the cursor to jump to the next capital, that works fine. It's the widening behavior that still feels off to me.

Comment: @mpen In the first movie, at 00:38, I see that your selection expands to cover *World* (limited bu capital and dot), then to cover *selectWorld* (limited by dot and dot), then to cover *smart.selectWorld.stuff* (limited by quotation marks). To verify your last comment - that is **not** the desired behavior? What exactly is in this particular text sequence, if you'd express it in words? (I just can't wave it off and really want to prove that VSC rocks (fearing that maybe it doesn't as much as I believe).

Comment: @mpen By watching both movies again, it seems to be that you want the selection to grow to the delimiters **except** capital letter. Is that correctly understood? Basically, you want the camelization to be disregarded when you widen your selection and mark the whole word at once (independent of whether *itHappensToLookLikeThis* or *ithappenstolooklikethis*). Do I got your expectation right?

Comment: The JSON example is worse. In the video, I first put my cursor in "The" and expand. It selects "The". That's not too bad because I can just expand again if I want more, but to me, "whatTheDuck" should be one logical unit, so it should be the next thing to be selected. But VSC thinks the entire string is the next unit up from that, skipping over whatTheDuck. And then the most egregious thing I think is that what I put my cursor in "Baz" and expand, it selects "Baz.buck.what" instead of "barBaz" which makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: None of these examples are particularly great though because they're all inside of strings, so I wouldn't fault VSC terribly if it decided that the next unit was the whole string. It's much worse when it does it with actual variables.

Comment: https://mpen.xyz/share/2021/04/2021-04-18_11-41-12.mp4  like what is this. First it selects "baz" which is great. But then it decides to expand over 2 vars to left. Why left, not right? Why not the whole var? And then it expands *one* var to the right. Why 1 this time and not 2 vars? It's not predictable. The whole point of smart select is that I tap my hotkey some logical number of times and then start typing my new var name immediately. I uses to much brain power to try and guess what it's going to do and inspect if it did it right.